# Jquery Ajax No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, firebase

I have been struggling with this day for days now, not sure where the problem is. Running long request makes the page timeout and I get this return error:

`from origin 'xxxxxxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` after 2 mins

Front end is jQuery/Ajax that makes a `POST` request to the backend running on `nodejs` `Firebase`. Everything works if the request is less than 2mins. This issue applies to POST with large CSV file, or DELETE that takes a while from the backend.

I have tried:

1. Adding `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` to Ajax, no luck
2. Modified sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf KeepAlive, no luck
3. Added `"key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",` to firebase config header file, no luck

How else can I run a loop that takes times while keeping the page alive for like 3-5 mins?

Comment: Do you have the relevant headers on the requested server though?

Comment: Yes, I have cors defined as "*" and it works if the data isn't large. It's like a timeout from the client to server but not sure where to solve this issue

Comment: maybe its also a browser timeout? is there a way to chunk the request into more requests or what exactly takes so long?

Comment: I have a large JSON sent to the server via Ajax POST .. everything actually completes if I refresh the page. But before refreshing, the response comes as error. I guess the other option might to chunk the data of course